# Fuzzy c means coming up with an invalid syntax error even though it has already been successully installed on Google Colabatory

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

As tittle is explained, I used !pip install, using both --upgrade and also without it. For some reason it still refused to work.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXfdw.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljW4h.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by using:

```
!pip install fuzzy-c-means
```

Then,

```
from fcmeans import FCM
```